# AngularJS - A directive to manage collection of directives is not being bound/rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

'm new to angular so guessing this is an easy question to answer.

I have written a couple of directives that essentially are controls. I want to write another directive that manages a collection of these controls.

What I have learnt is that I'd need an array of data to which to bind to, each would represent the data for each child directive.

What I am unsure of is how I would implement it.  For example, do you have to manually compile the html for each new control added, or is this take care of?

I've seen examples where people use `$compile` in the link function, but doesn't seem correct unless you're needing to manually compile for some reason.

Additionally, each child directive would render a button that allowed itself to be removed from the parent collection. Is there a way of binding a function to the parent controller?

EDIT:

As suggested, here is the basis of what I'm doing.  It's not working at the moment, so considering building the HTML in the link function and calling `$compile`

```
.directive('fsFilterCollection', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',        
        priority: 1002,
        scope: {
            filters: "=",
            filterClosedFn: '&'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {              
            $scope.filterClosedFn = function (filterdata) {
                console.log("filter closed")
            }
        },
        template: function (element, attr) {
            return  '<div>'+
                    '   <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">'+
                    '     <div>',
                    '          <div fs-dummy-filter keepopen="true" filter-closed-fn="filterClosedFn()" filterdata="item.filterdata" fs-filter actions="true" filter-type="item.filterType"></div>' +
                    '       </div>'+
                    '   </div>'+
                    '</div>'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            console.log(scope.filters);
        }
    }
})

.directive('fsDummyFilter', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',     
        priority: 1001,
        scope: {
            isopen: '=',  
            filterdata: "=",
            filterClosedFn: '&'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        },
        template: function (element, attr) {
            return '<div>{{filterdata.filterType}}<button ng-click="filter-closed-fn()(filterdata)">Close</button></div>';
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        }
    }
})
```

The HTML is

```
<div fs-filter-collection filters="filters"></div>
```

and the controller for this defines:

```
$scope.filters = [
    { filterType:"String" }
];
```

The issue I have is that the filterCollection directive is not rendering the child directive.  I've checked the value of `filters` in the link function and they are set from the parent controller.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to know. You want to have a directive inside another directive, is that it? This shouldn't be a problem at all, when linking a directive all directives inside are also linked. It would be best you give it a try first and come back with a more _specific_ question, because frankly this one is quite broad and unclear.

Comment: sure, give me a min, I'll update with what I have

Comment: not really. It improves the question, but I still don't get your problem. What do you actually want to achieve, what are the "child controls" you are talking about, where are they in your code? Is it `fs-filter`? If you, you might want to show us the code for this as well. Also, ` It's not working at the moment` is no error description - What exactly does not work, any JS errors or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @dirkk thanks for feedback. does that make it any easier to help?

Comment: Please look at console log for errors. I believe the `template` function should return a single root. Wrap your `ng-repeat` code in a div\span

Comment: thanks @Chandermani - i have just tried that without success. no errors in console

Answer (score 0):

my bad. in my template i was using `item.filterType` is should have been `filter.filterType`

No error reported by angular which made debugging difficult, but may help someone.

Thanks for comments anyway!